# How to set-up In App Purchase free trial period in iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In Apple's AppStore Terms & Conditions, you may find the following statement in relation to Auto-renewable In App Purchases:

> "Certain paid In App Subscriptions may offer a free trial period prior to charging your Account."

How does it work? I haven't seen any option to allow such free trial period for my Auto-renewable IAPs in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Apple AppStore Terms & Conditions (USA): http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html

Answer (score 94):

Works for 2020.03.16

**8 steps in detail**

**1**

[image: 0]

**2**

[image: 1]

**3**

[image: 2]

**4**

[image: 3]

**5**

[image: 4]

**6**

[image: 5]

**7**

[image: 6]

**8**

[image: 7]

**And you got**

[image: 8]

After several hours, it works

Comment: Is there any need to check receipts in the code or will the above set-up handle de-activation of the app when the trial period is over and the subscription has been cancelled -  and also at the end of the subscription period but subscription cancelled?  I'd prefer to have all this managed outside of the code if possible.

Comment: Your suggestion is not of Apple

Comment: 2020 in changes this is Perfect answer.

Comment: after setup in apple is there anything do in our end ie,code to check any introductory offer or anything?

Comment: You can try other answers, like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511546/how-to-support-offer-ios-subscriptions-with-a-free-trial-period

Comment: I have an auto-renewable subscription with 1 week free trial period. Apple is handling this after adding the subscription. My question is after adding the subscription and free trial period, in my simulator it shows the trial period and the start date as expected. But in the real device it not shows as expected.

Comment: Great answer, but product does not have to be approved

Comment: in 2023 works perfect

Comment: setting No End Date did the trick.

Answer (score 39):

Five years later - Apple has changed the way you offer free trial for users.
source: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/4406427

From now it's under "introductory price", see here for more details:
https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve1d49254f
[image: Select Set Up Introductory Price]

Update 3/2020: now it's called "Create Introductory Offer"
[image: update for]

Comment: do you know how can we get the free trial period for ios versions before 11.2. My UI shows how many days the trial is for. I'm getting this from SKProductDiscount object. How can I do the same(show trial period for different products dynamically) for versions iOS 11.2 earlier ?

Answer (score 33):

As of **October 2019**, follow this :

In iTunes, Select My apps --> features --> In-app purchases

1. Click on Product ID
2. Subscription Prices
3. Create introductory offer
4. Select territory
5. Choose start and End date. Select today's date and **No end date if it's Free Trial.**
6. Select type (Trial) and duration of trial.

During receipt validation in server side, you can check for *is_trial_period* to determine if it is in Trial.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app

Answer (score 4):

After you log in to iTunesConnect...

- Select Manage Your Apps.

[image: Manage Your Apps]

- Select your app.
- Select Manage In-App Purchases.

[image: Manage In-App Purchases]

- Select the subscription family you want to add a free trial to.
- Select a duration.

[image: Durations]

- Set Offer a free trial? to Yes.
- Select free trial duration.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For 2023, in Appstore Connect create 1 week free trial:

1- Select App

2- Subscriptions

3- Select Subscription group
[image]

4- Select Subscription
[image: Select Subscription]

5-
Click plus near Subscription Prices and Create Introductory Offer
[image]

6- Select all Countries, Start day today, end date No end date.

7- Select duration 7-day trial or as you want.

Answer (score -1):

In iTunes Connect

App > Manage In App Purchases > Subscription Basic > 1 Month >  Offer a free trial?

Comment: Before one month if the user cancels the subscription will that app will available to the user.