# In app purchases Auto-renewable Subscription : Where to specify free trial

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Where in iTunesConnect, can I specify free trial. Apple docs say that for auto-renewable subscription in app purchases, we can offer free trial and marketing opt-in incentives. I can see option to set marketing opt-in incentives but not for free trial. Do I need to code the app to handle this?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297342/how-to-set-up-in-app-purchase-free-trial-period-in-ios-app/47769055#47769055

Comment: Answered here (Latest 2019) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381292/1522584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App > Manage In App Purchases > Subscription Basic > 1 Month >  Offer a free trial? > Yes