# How to set a free trial for auto-renewable subscriptions (not on newsstand)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

been trying to implement a free trial on a non consumable auto-renewable subscription, but can't seen to find it.

Read stuff here telling me that it's possible if its on newstand, but this does not seem to me to be a way, as my app is about videos.

I have seen that Qello is doing it, does anyone know how to set it?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21062896/2880276).