# How to give each user a free trail period

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have developed in IOS application i want to distribute the application in subscription basis like first 15 days it should be trail after that user has to pay the price decided for the app .Is it possible to do it from apple developer account?

Comment: Afaik this is possible only for In App Purchases, not for apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297342/how-to-set-up-in-app-purchase-free-trial-period-in-ios-app what about this

Comment: You need to do this in code, store an NSDate when the app is first launched. Then after 15 days you can disable doing anything in your app until the user has done the in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are few simple steps you to achieve subscription base App upload.

Step 1: [image: choose you product type automatically renewable subscription]

Step 2: [image: enter duration for subscription and free trail]

Comment: Apple has changed the way you offer free trail for users. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297342/how-to-set-up-in-app-purchase-free-trial-period-in-ios-app/47769055#47769055